# Probability of getting a specific hand in Hearthstone (Online Card Game)

Tags: probability

For the sake of learning, I am trying to understand how to calculate the odds of getting a winning combination of cards within a online card game (Hearthstone, for you Blizzard fans out there).  My knowledge of statistics & statistics notation is minimal, but I am hoping to use this an an opportunity to expand my horizons a bit.

Here's the problem:  Let's say that I have a winning hand combination if I am able to have 3 specific cards by turn 3 in the game.  Let's call them Card A, Card B, & Card C. The goal is to calculate the odds of starting my 3rd with one copy of A, B, and C in my hand.

Here are some of the parameters:

1. I have a total of 30 cards in my deck.
2. Within the deck, I have 2 copies of A, 2 copies of B, and only 1 copy of C.
3. I start the game by drawing 8 cards (In the game, I actually draw 4 and then
   can return & redraw any unwanted cards, but I don't want to muddy
   the water too much).
4. At the beginning of each turn, I draw 1
   card.

What are the odds of my getting the "winning hand"?  Can guide me where to learn more about the method that you use to answer the problem?

Comment: The subject is combinatorics.  It is a big one.  Getting things counted accurately has many pitfalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The winning combinations are ABC, AABC, ABBC, AABBC, where the unshown cards are among the other $25$.  This gives ${2 \choose 1}{2 \choose 1}{25 \choose 8}+2{2 \choose 1}{25 \choose 7}+{25 \choose 6}=6426200$.  Dividing by ${30 \choose 11}$ gives about $11.76\%$

Comment: What does (21) mean? The 2 above the 1

Comment: @Draken:  $25 \choose 8$ is the number of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of $8$ things chosen from $25$.  The formula would be $\frac {25!}{8!(25-8)!}$  The Wikipedia link explains it.

Comment: Appreciated, thanks!